# Converting from Windows-1255 to UTF-8 encoding in Objective-C or PHP

Tags: php, xcode, encoding, utf-8

I am developing an iPhone app in Xcode which brings data from the `SQL` database of a Hebrew-language web site. This database uses `Windows-1255` encoding for all of its tables. When I pull data from this database to my app, it shows up as gibberish, so I think it's not being translated from the `Windows-1255` encoding to the `UTF-8` encoding that I want to use for data in my app.

How can I convert the data to `UTF-8` in Xcode? Can I add something to the query so that the database itself will send data already translated to `UTF-8` instead of sending me data encoded in `Windows-1255`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/function.iconv.php)  PHP function. It always worked perfectly for me.

Comment: I tried it this way: $text = iconv('cp-1255','utf-8',$row['name']);
   $names[]  = $text;  but i get an empty string

Comment: Also read users' comments. There is one about converting Windows-1255 to utf-8 another way than iconv() function with an example code.

Comment: The function works eventually, there was something else that ruined it. Thank Alot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are receiving this data as an `NSData' type. What you need to do is use the method:

```
- (id)initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding
```

on `NSString`. Get the bytes from the data and pass that as the bytes. The only thing is I don't really see an encoding type for 1255 - the list is [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/String_Encodings).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

For PHP you can use this function : 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php

Note you need to do this right after you connect to your database.

Comment: I tried it but the text in the db is already in windows-1255 so it doesnt matter when I try to extract it